# warning with environmental variables. can't connect to database

Tags: php, wordpress, environment-variables

I just finished making an .env file for my wordpress project and when I finished typing in all the values the backend of my wordpress won't work. It says it can't connect to the database. this is the error:

```
Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/vagrant/Code/creativeforces/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1489
```

Here is my wp-config.php:

```
define('DB_NAME', getenv('DB_NAME'));

// /** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', getenv('DB_USER'));

// /** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', getenv('DB_PASSWORD'));

// /** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', getenv('DB_HOST'));

// /** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', getenv('DB_CHARSET'));

// /** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define('DB_COLLATE', getenv('DB_COLLIATE'));

define('AUTH_KEY', getenv('AUTH_KEY'));
define('SECURE_AUTH_KEY', getenv('SECURE_AUTH_KEY'));
define('LOGGED_IN_KEY', getenv('LOGGED_IN_KEY'));
define('NONCE_KEY',    getenv('NONCE_KEY'));
define('AUTH_SALT',  getenv('AUTH_SALT'));
define('SECURE_AUTH_SALT', getenv('SECURE_AUTH_SALT'));
define('LOGGED_IN_SALT',   getenv('LOGGED_IN_SALT'));
define('NONCE_SALT',    getenv('NONCE_SALT'));
```

I'm not sure why it's not connecting to my env file.
Here is an image of my file structure:
[image]

also this is what my .env file looks like but these are not the values I have. These are just examples.

```
DB_NAME=cupcakelife
DB_HOST=44.33.22
DB_DATABASE=cupcake
DB_USER=cupcake
DB_PASSWORD=bakinglife
DB_CHARSET=dewqdwe
DB_COLLIATE='dewqdfwrfvgerwfgrewfvwerferw'
```

any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so getenv() gets the value of environment variables. AFAIK, Vagrant's vars from .env aren't populated to that scope unless you specifically tell it to.
Check this out: https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv it should do the trick for you.

Comment: Thank you so much! Finally got it!